# Custom order by, is it possible?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following collection:

> -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3

How can I in a single `order by` statement sort them in the following form:

The negative numbers are sorted first by their (absolute value) then the positive numbers.

> -1, -2, -3, 0, 1, 2, 3

Comment: Looks like homework: why have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @Richard : No, it's not a homework, but in a list of Accounts, Groups. I save the groups with negative ids (to keep the ids unique) I just want to sort them in UI (groups (sorted) then users (sorted)). That's all.

Comment: @ geek: No need, seems lasseespeholt [has answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741870/custom-order-by-is-it-possible/5741943#5741943).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Combination sorting, first by the sign, then by the absolute value:

```
list.OrderBy(x => Math.Sign(x)).ThenBy(x => Math.Abs(x));
```

or:

```
from x in list
orderby Math.Sign(x), Math.Abs(x)
select x;
```

This is conceptually similar to the SQL statement:

```
SELECT x
FROM list
ORDER BY SIGN(x), ABS(x)
```

In LINQ-to-Objects, the sort is performed only once, not twice.

*WARNING: Math.Abs(x) will fail if x == int.MinValue.  If this marginal case is important, then you have to handle it separately.*

Comment: +1 I like it :) However, it does have the same limit as mime. You can't take abs of `int.MinValue`.

Comment: +1 :-)  However, code simplicity and clarity better than to trap the last marginal case, IMHO...

Comment: I agree, but I just think OP should know :)

Comment: @ lasseespeholt: Actually in my case I don't have the `int.MinValue` problem. It's a list of Ids.

Answer (score 6):

```
var numbers = new[] { -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3 };

var customSorted = numbers.OrderBy(n => n < 0 ? int.MinValue - n : n);
```

The idea here is to compare non-negative numbers by the value they have. And compare negative numbers with the value `int.MinValue - n` which is `-2147483648 - n` and because `n` is negative, the higher negative number we, the lower negative result the outcome will be.

It doesn't work when the list itself contains the number `int.MinValue` because this evaluates to `0` which would be equal to `0` itself. As Richard propose it could be made with `long`´s if you need the full range but the performance will be slightly impaired by this.

Comment: Depending on the range of input ints, doing the sort on longs might be safer, but this is the solution I came up with.

Comment: @Richard Yes, I've updated the answer to reflect the range of inputs. Only `int.MinValue` appears to break it.

Comment: @Magnus No, not if `int.MinValue` is after `0` :)

Comment: @lasseespeholt Yeh, your right. Something like this might do it: numbers.OrderBy(n => n < 0 ? (int.MinValue - n  == 0 ? -1 : int.MinValue - n) : n);

Comment: @Magnus Hhm, then the problem would be sorting between `int.MinValue` and `int.MinValue + 1`?

Comment: @lasseespeholt et al: If `Int.MinValue` needs to be included in the valid input domain, then perform all the operations on `long`. Also I would expect little performance impact from using `long` (current CPUs operate on 64bit numeric values as they do on 32bit), unless cache size becomes a factor. However doing a two stage sort (`Sign(x)` then `Abs(x)` and therefore not needing a type conversion also has overheads: I would expect the difference would only show up in very large datasets (1MB cache can hold >130k long values...).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like (VB.Net example)

```
Orderby(Function(x) iif(x<0, Math.Abs(x), x*1000))
```

...if the values are <1000

Answer (score 0):

You could express it in LINQ, but if I were reading the code two years later, I'd prefer to see something like:

```
list.OrderBy(i=>i, new NegativeThenPositiveByAscendingAbsoluteValueComparer());
```

You will need to implement IComparer.